# Confusion: evaluating a two-dimensional function given a thridimensional point?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was requested to find the partial derivatives (for each variable) of $w = e^{y \ln z}$. I  was able to determine without too much trouble that

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}=z^y \ln z \\ \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}=yz^{y-1}$$

However, I was then asked to find the value of the function at the point $(e, 2, e)$. I understood $w$ to simply equal $f(z, y)$, a function of two variables, and was completely thrown away by being ask to find its value given the three arguments. How am I suppose to evaluate $w$ in the given point?

I know this must be a very simple question, but I only started studying this today. I self study and don't have any professors or classmates to run this by, so I thought I'd come here. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear from the context. My guess is that $w=w(x,y,z)=0\cdot x+e^{y\ln z}$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. At least now I know it was not me missunderstanding something. It may even be a typo in the excercise sheet...